# Minimum length of double value in a column in Impala table

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

I am trying to find the minimum length by getting the length of each values in a column (double) in a table and running a min function on top of it to get the minimum length.

This works well when the column is a string type but the 'length' function does not work for double datatype in impala, what is the other way to address this?

```
min(length(columnname))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All double columns are 8 bytes, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_double.html).  `LENGTH()` is a string function and it doesn't really make sense on a numeric value (although you can convert to a string and then measure the length).